# import or load .net website in visual studios

Tags: asp.net

I am really new to web development in .Net with Visual Studios.  So I wasn't sure what keywords to query in search engine to solve my problem.

Anyway, I inherited a .Net website project.  Except for just 3 .aspx.cs files, pretty much every other file is a .aspx file.

I don't see any .csproj or any .sln files.

**If I want to load up this website on my localhost, how would I go about doing it?  Am I supposed to load up Visual Studios and "import" these *.aspx.cs and *.aspx file?**

I already successfully set up the SQL Server database and updated the web.config with the appropriate credentials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use File->Open->Web Site.

Comment: I keep getting errors like "Error 1 The file '/en/en/Controls/Popup.ascx.cs' does not exist."...But the file DOES exist.  When I look in the ascx file, I see "~/en/Controls/Popup.ascx.cs"....Do I need to configure Visual Studios to define where the ~ tilda is supposed to server pages from?

Comment: I think that's a Web Application Project, and  you've just lost the .csproj. If necessary, you can create a new, empty ASP.NET Web Application project, press F5 to make sure it works, then copy the files and folders from the original over the new one. Click your project, then use "Project->Show all files", select the files, right-click and choose "Include in project".